# Issues with compiled_templates - call to undefined method

Tags: templating, error-message

We have two web servers in a load-balanced setup. Both servers are sharing a single database. The craft and public folders are rsync-ed between the two so changes on those folders in web1 propagate into web2.

We tried loading a video atom using the following twig:

```
{% case "video" %}
{{ atom.video(block) }}
```

It works on our local dev copy and on our staging server at AWS, however on our live site we get this error:

[image: Getting an undefined method error]

I tried copying the whole runtime folder from AWS over to the live web servers but that did not fix it.

Any ideas on how to get it to work? I would consider myself a novice to Craft so pardon me if there's something obvious that I'm missing.

Thanks in advance.

**Update:**

Already figured out that it was an error with the upload. Some macros were not properly copied over into live.

Comment: What is `atom` and `video`?  Are they coming from a plugin?

Comment: Thanks for asking this question. I went to double check both on our staging and live servers. The video atom thing is a macro that we made and it didn't exist on the live server. Must have been an issue with the upload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is my bad. Thanks to Brad Bell, I went to check whether the macros were on both the staging and live servers. The macros existed on staging but not on live.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this a couple of times, and have yet to figure out what causes it, but on my server deleting the `compiled_templates` folder (`app/craft/storage/runtime/compiled_templates`) fixes it.